# TextView unexpected padding

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

The `RecyclerView` shows simple items. Each item has one `TextView` inside `FrameLayout`. `TextView` has no any paddings, but in some cases they appears unexpectedly. The picture below shows that the padding appears immediately after opening the keyboard. The padding appears only if the text contains newline characters. How to fix it ?

[image]

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var adapter : MyAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val recyclerView : RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        val button : Button = findViewById(R.id.button)

        adapter = MyAdapter();
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter;

        button.setOnClickListener {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    }
}

class MyViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val textView: TextView;

    init {
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.txt)
    }
}

class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {

    private val data = listOf("Text without \\n ", "multiline\ntext")

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false))

    override fun getItemCount() = data.size;

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.textView.text = data[position]
    }

}
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:id="@+id/txt"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
            android:text="notifyDataSetChanged"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    />
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried `.trim()` method to string

Comment: is there any reason to use framelayout? 
Can you use a constraint layout in your item and align your text view start to parent and set the width to 0dp?

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />